# Linq2EF: Concat all values in another table into a string

Tags: linq-to-entities, concatenation, aggregation

Let's say I have two entities:

```
Physician
Credentials
```

And a physician can have many credentials, such as Dr. Jones can have MD, DO, MPH as credentials. So I need to generate a report via Linq that concatenates the credentials into a single string. For example:

```
from p in Physicians
select
{
   p.Name
   p.Credentials (??? <- concatenated list of all credentials ?????)
}
```

I have played with "`p.Credentials.Aggregate((a,b) => a.Abrev + ',' + b.Abrev)`" to no avail, but I'm not sure I have the syntax correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhm.... I've not tested it, but you can try:

```
from p in Physicians
select
{
   p.Name,
   String.Join(",", p.Credentials.Select<Credentials, string>(c=>c.Abrev).ToArray())
}
```

Into the Select, I think x must be Credential, not Credentials...

**EDIT**

You need to move your objects into memory, try adding ToList() before make the Select

```
from p in Physicians.Include("Credentials").ToList()
select new
{
    p.Name,
    Credentials = String.Join(",", p.Credentials.Select<Credentials, string>(c=>c.Abrev).ToArray())
}
```

Comment: The problem is Linq2Entities does not allow String.Join as this cannot be executed on SQL Server.

Comment: With Aggregate your synthax is similar to .Aggregate("", (a,b) => b.Abrev + ", " + a) but you also need to first apply ToList(), because LinqToEntities seems to not support Aggregate.